# "Sehr viel" + Komparativ - Grammatisch korrekt?

Tags: adjective, comparative

Neulich habe ich den folgenden Satz in einem Buch gelesen "Allen anderen ginge es schliesslich "sehr viel schlechter" als Deutschland". Beim Lesen habe ich mich gewundert, ob Formulierungen wie diese grammatisch korrekt sind, in der neben einem gesteigerten Adjektiv noch ein Verstärkungswort ("sehr") hinzukommt.

Darüber hinaus sagt mein Sprachgefühl, "viel schlechter" entspricht "much worse" auf Englisch, aber "sehr viel schlechter" hätte kein denkbares Gegenstück. Was sagt ihr?

Comment: Das klingt für mich (norddeutsch) vollkommen normal.

Comment: Das klingt für mich (aus Österreich) vollkommen normal.

Comment: Die Frage, wie man es ins Englische übersetzen würde, ist hier eigentlich off-topic. Dafür ist ein Forum für englische Sprache geeignet. _much much worse_ oder _a lot worse_ würde ich sagen, aber ich bin kein Muttersprachler.

Comment: [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sehr+viel+schlechter%2Csehr+schlechter%2Cviel+schlechter&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3). Seems like all combinations are allowed.

Comment: I would think the direct translation of "sehr viel schlechter" is just "very much worse".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das ist vollkommen korrekt, nichts spricht dagegen.

In der Mathematik gibt es z.B. auch ein Zeichen, das "[sehr viel größer als](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+22D9)" heißt: ⋙
Und natürlich gibt es auch "[sehr viel kleiner als](https://www.compart.com/de/unicode/U+22D8)": ⋘

Die Wortfolge "sehr viel teurer" findet man in unzähligen Titeln von Zeitungsartikeln:

- [Studie »Nature« zum Autofahren: Sehr viel teurer](https://bicicli.de/magazin-radar/news/autofahren_kosten_bicicli/)
- [Stützmauer sehr viel teurer](https://www.neckar-chronik.de/Nachrichten/Stuetzmauer-sehr-viel-teurer-418698.html)
- [Dieser Konflikt ist für China sehr viel teurer](https://www.dw.com/de/dieser-konflikt-ist-f%C3%BCr-china-sehr-viel-teurer/a-48722457)

Oder auch »sehr viel länger«:

- [Die Reserven halten sehr viel länger](https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/die-reserven-halten-sehr-viel-laenger.694.de.html?dram:article_id=65864)
- [Es dauert alles sehr viel länger als geplant](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/fluechtlinge-in-turnhallen-es-dauert-alles-sehr-viel-laenger-als-geplant/14428074.html)

Gerne auch zweimal in derselben Überschrift:

- [Die Schweiz hat historisch sehr viel länger sehr viel besser gelebt](https://www.derbund.ch/schweiz/standard/die-schweiz-hat-historisch-sehr-viel-laenger-sehr-viel-besser-gelebt/story/23017550)

Wie man sieht, wird die Kombination »sehr viel« + Komparativ sehr viel häufiger verwendet als man vermuten würde.

Answer (score 11):

Das ist eine gängige Art der besonderen Betonung und grammatikalisch vollkommen richtig. Manchmal hört man auch Varianten mit verdoppeltem Adjektiv (viel viel schlechter), aber hier bin ich nicht sicher, ob das nicht ein aus dem englischen übernommener Terminus ist (much much worse).

Es gibt auch andere ähnliche Kombinationen wie:

> Und ich fühlte mich ein bisschen weniger schlecht